# Faster way to extract close pairs from two arrays?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Suppose I have two random arrays of `int`s, say:

```
int A[] = {484, 834, 591, 23, 174, 248, 147, 765};
int B[] = {659, 805, 12, 180, 771, 386, 354, 568, 710, 312, 6, 848};
```

I wish to find all close pairs respectively from the two arrays, where the difference between two `int`s are not greater than some fixed `k` like `50`:

```
(from A, from B)
(834, 805)
(834, 848)
(591, 568)
(23, 12)
(23, 6)
(174, 180)
(147, 180)
(765, 805)
(765, 771)
```

The trivial way to do that is using a nested `for` loop:

```
for (int a : A) {
  for (int b : B) {
    if (abs(a - b) < k)
      // find (a, b)
  }
}
```

but this requires `O(n^2)` time complexity and seems not efficient. Is there a better way to do that, regardless of space cost?

Comment: I'd start with removing the syntactic sugar, and checking for bottlenecks using a measurement. But I doubt there is a faster way. Give us a complete example, it may  depend on the concrete context, if there's potential for optimization.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you for your reply, I change the description.

Comment: A simple improvement is to use binary search to find one of the extremes and use that as the starting point. That's log(n) instead of n and makes the total O(n*(log n + k))) but given that k is fixed that's better.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Hmm, I'd say the potential for optimization might lie  in using a different data structure, which is optimized for the conditions you're looking for.

Comment: the "adjacent" is confusing me. In what sense are they adjacent? Only by having a difference less than 50 ?

Comment: @idclev 463035818. Yes.

Comment: no native speaker, but I think that then "adjacent" is the wrong word, because in `1 2 42` the `1` and `42` are not adjacent. Don't worry, I am a bit slow sometimes, seems like everybody else understood what you mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might do in `O(N log N)` (+ number of resulting pairs (which might exceed `N log N`)):

```
std::sort(std::begin(A), std::end(A)); // O(N log N)
std::sort(std::begin(B), std::end(B)); // O(N log N)

auto begin = std::begin(B);
auto end = begin;
for (auto v : A) {
    while (begin != std::end(B) && *begin < v - 50) ++begin;
    while (end != std::end(B) && *end < v + 50) ++end;
    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        std::cout << '(' << v << ", " << *it << ")\n";
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/020c04e3dfe2b150)

Comment: Note that this is n^2 worst case if elements need bit be unique. Still correct in that case though afaics

Comment: I think `begin` should be initial with `std::lower_bound` and `end` should be initial with `std::upper_bound`, and in nested loop they should be assign with `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` as well.

Comment: @康桓瑋: Once sorted, we are linear (except to display results): we iterate `A` once with the for range. Both `begin`/`end` iterate `B` once so `A.size() + 2 * B.size()`. Using `lower_bound` (in the loop) would introduce N logarithmic searches. I think it is a wrong good idea.

Comment: @Voo: size of result might indeed be `O(N²)`. Not sure what you meant about uniqueness (filter duplicates from input `A` and `B` is linear once sorted)...

Comment: @jarod42 If the elements are all unique the result will be in `O(n log n)`. If there might be duplicates in the array you can end up with `O(n^2)` (i.e. worst case all elements are identical you end up with the cartesian product as the result).

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh I just noticed that my phone decided to change not to bit, which is rather confusing. I hope the previous explanation makes it clearer.

Comment: @Voo: I though that even without doublons we might have `O(n²)` resulting pairs, but it is *only* `2*k*N`. which confuse me even more about uniqueness.

Comment: @Jarod42 My reasoning: You have to sort the arrays so that makes it O(n log n) (well ignoring non-comparison sorts like radix sort). But afterwards you're iterating through A once. B is moved from beginning to end with each element being accessed at most k times thanks to the uniqueness constraint which is O(N*k). With duplicates the worst case is where all elements are equal which means the result is the cartesian product whose cardinality is |A| * |B| which is n^2.

Answer (score 1):

Try a) binary searching the second array b) remembering previous positions in the second array and c) tracking the distance between elements in the first array. The first step is log(n) instead of n, and the second step makes the search space smaller for later searches. The third step reuses previous distance calculations.

For example, binary search for items with max distance 50 from 432, giving you the lowest and highest indexes, 3 and 6. For the next element, 615, you can ignore items below the lowest index 3. That's a) and b). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Procedure_for_finding_the_leftmost_element

For many arrays, you can save calculations by storing the max distance values of previous searches. For 427 you would store 394 and 473, their index and distance values, i.e. (3,-33) and (6,46). Suppose the next item was 430. Now, instead of doing the binary search, you can just check the distance with the previous element, abs(430-427), and subtract it from the stored distances, giving you -36 and 43. You can then conclude 430 has a superset of the distance set of 427 without searching those elements. Suppose the next value is 615. This gives you abs(615-427) or 188, so you get -221 and -142. Both are too large, so you can skip all of them, starting the binary search of a) with index 7 (6+1), instead of 3.

NB edit: OP is no longer the same, the arrays were sorted and had different values.

Comment: The worst case isn't n^2 assuming elements are unique and that k is a fixed size.

Comment: @Voo does uniqueness matter? I removed the part about assumed worst-case complexity and changed the text a bit. Right now it looks like it's n log n, even with duplicates, or am I missing something?

Comment: Assume all elements in A and B are equal, in that case the result should be the cartesian product of the two sets. The cardinality of the cartesian product |A x B| is |A| * |B|. So if you allow duplicates and do better than n^2 you're missing some pairs.

Comment: @Voo I don't think that's necessary, it depends on the data representation of the output, and the question AFAICT was about how many abs calls are made, not about the output. Suppose you have [1,1,1] and [1,1,1]. The naive implementation is to output 1 => [1,1,1] three times. Another possibility is to use the superset idea c) to make it 0 => [0,2], 1 => link(0), 2 = link(0), that is, to link to shared segments. Left-hand side is index in A, right-hand side is range in B. You don't need to re-examine every pair in a range of elements because both arrays are sorted. See the c) part again.

Comment: The output shown in the question for your sets would be `(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),..` as far as I can see. It also says "I wish to find all close pairs" nothing about abs calls. I guess you might be able to optimize this to `6x (1,1)` but I'd want to see the detailed algorithm first - the devil's in the details for these things.

Comment: @Voo but how are you measuring the complexity then? To me, it's obvious to select the innermost function and measure how many times it is called.

Comment: @Voo it is easy to optimize with the c) part of my post. After you check the first item, you store the min/max indexes that are valid and their distances to the item, (0,0) and (2,0). Now, when you check the second item, you can just calculate d(first item, second item) = 0 and add that to both endpoints, and see that the range is exactly the same. You don't have to examine the middle element at index 1 again. In this case, the benefit is negligible, as we save one check, but with 50 elements, you still only need to examine the endpoints. This method only works if the arrays are sorted.

Comment: "how are you measuring the complexity". Oh you always have to decide what you want to measure absolutely. The usual default is "growth of the function for computing the expected result". Which yes makes a very big difference. If the expected output is a list of all pairs, you simply cannot do better than O(n^2) - if you're fine with a different representation of the output you might be able to do better.

Comment: Just "count number of times inner function is called" can be misleading if an optimization introduces overhead in another area - with just a textual representation I won't be trying to analyze a more complex algorithm. Not saying it's wrong, just that it's too complex for me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Jarod42's answer, I tried to distill everything down to standard algorithms and containers and was able to get something like this

```
#include <set>

void print_close_pairs(vector<int> const& A, vector<int> const & B){
    auto a = std::multiset<int>(A.cbegin(),A.cend()); // O(n * log(n))
    auto b = std::multiset<int>(B.cbegin(),B.cend()); // O(m * log(m))

    for (auto v: a){ // O(n)
        auto beg = b.lower_bound(v - 50); // O(log(m))
        auto end = b.upper_bound(v + 50); // O(log(m))
        for (; beg != end; beg++) { // O(m)
            std::cout << '(' << v << ", " << *beg << ")\n";
        }
    }
}
```

We see that A and B need to be treated as separate complexity variables *n* and *m* respectively. We also find that only one of the inputs needs to be put into a set (or sorted). So while we can't escape O(n * m) complexity, we are still doing a lot of extra work.

```
void mark_pairs(vector<int> const& A, vector<int> const & B){
    auto b = std::multiset<int>(B.cbegin(),B.cend()); // O(m * log(m))

    for (auto v: A){ // O(n)
        auto beg = b.lower_bound(v - 50); // O(log(m))
        auto end = b.upper_bound(v + 50); // O(log(m))
        for (; beg != end; beg++) { // O(m)
            std::cout << '(' << v << ", " << *beg << ")\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Beyond that, there are few more things that you could do to massage the data to only work on the smallest subsets, but I think you're really limited to a O(n*m) complexity.

Side note: beware of *only* sorting, because you could accidentally hit worst case time complexity of O(n² + m²) complexity

Comment: Your `lower_bound` calls makes the second part `O(n log m)` whereas mine is linear (but require sorted input (`O(n log n)`)). (I would also treat result size as other variable to allow `O(max(N log N, M log M, result_size)))` discussion/comparison.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes. One of the extensions that I was thinking about was selecting the shorter vector to build the multiset, and the other as the "search key". The second function operates as `O(m * log (m)) + O(n (2*log(m) + m))` since `m` dominates the equation, creating the multiset from the smaller of the two arrays would likely improve the speed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to exploit the fact that there is no space cost and the fact that we deal with integers, and use it to find an algorithm in time `O(n)` or as Alex defined each array length with different variable (and I completely agree) `O(n+m)`.

1. Go over the first array (call it A - length=n) and define a new array where each cell points to a linked list, the linked list will contain all relevant items from A. for every element a, add its number to linked lists at locations [a-50:a+50]. This construction is `O(n)`
2. Go over each element in the second array (call it B - length =m), for each element b the relevant items from A are in cell b. Time complexity `O(m)`

Comment: `O(n+m)`... as `(k * numeric_limits<unsigned int>)` even if huge number is constant ;)